# CakePHP: how to use database view

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm using cake php and I baked a database view in my project using `cake bake model commission_items`. The *commission_items* is a MySQL view, to make selects simpler.

My problem is that when I use find() that data returned is not the same of the view.
When I run `select * from commission_items` in MySQL I get something like this:

```
user_id | item_id
------------------
20      | 400
```

And when I run the code below in cakephp, the result is messy.

```
$commissionTable = $this->loadModel( 'CommissionItems' );
$itemsToList = $commissionTable->find('all', array('limit'=>4, 'offset'=>3));
```

The result returns repeating some properties:

```
user_id | item_id
------------------
20      | 400
50      | 400
71      | 400
```

Would you have some tips for me to check? I've tried to clean `\tmp\cache\models` folder and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

By using sql query direct in database

```
select * from commission_items
```

In cakephp, you should use this once:

```
$commissionTable = $this->loadModel( 'CommissionItems' );
$itemsToList = $commissionTable->find('all');
```

Please remove offset and limit in cakephp parametter